# iPhone 4 font size too large to fit

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, iphone-4

I've developed an application for the iPhone, showing a UIAlertView with two buttons.  One that says "Cancel" and one that says "Send Challenge".

This works fine on the iPhone.  But on the iPhone 4, the "Send Challenge" gets truncated to "Send Challe..."

Seeing as how the iPhone 4 is supposed to be exactly the same as the iPhone just with twice as many pixels, it seems odd that the text isn't scaled up to be exactly twice the size as well.  Any thoughts on how to fix?  I've seen it happen in several places, but most of the other places, I was able to get around it by changing the label size by adding a few pixels. I don't think I can do that with a UIAlertView.

Comment: I *think* you can change the `UIAlertView` frame size. Don't quote me on that. You might also be able to change "Cancel" to "Exit" or "Send Challenge" to "Send". If you explain the prompt in the alert text, it shouldn't really matter what the buttons say on them.

Comment: I may end up going with the option to just change the text, rather than try to figure out why the iPhone 4 is broken, but it doesn't answer the question.  And would changing the UIAlertView's frame change the button frames?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't found a real solution to this other than changing the text to be shorter.  Really annoying that the iPhone 4 isn't exactly 2X from the iPhone.

Comment: On 1x, the system font is Helvetica. On 2x, it's Helvetica Neue. The metrics of the two fonts aren't identical.

Answer (score 0):

You can roll your own alert system. Try looking at the excellent [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) for tips on how you might be able to start with something like this